# looping through javascript object without sorting based on keys

Tags: javascript, object

this is the problem description:
Given an array of integers, calculate the fractions of its elements that are positive, negative, and are zeros. Print the decimal value of each fraction on a new line.
for example given the array `arr=[1,1,0,-1,-1]` output should be:

```
0.400000
0.400000
0.200000
```

I know there is more more simple solution for it ,and i am sorry for my silly simple question but i wanna make my code work, my code sorts the output based on the key and removes duplicates. for this arr, my code output is:

```
0.200000
0.400000
```

thank you so much in advance for any help.

```
function plusMinus(arr) {
    var freq = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if (freq[arr[i]]) {
            freq[arr[i]]++;
        } else {
            freq[arr[i]] = 1;
        }
    } for(var key in freq){

        console.log((freq[key]/arr.length).toFixed(6));
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's make sure the order of key in the map by defining it first.

```js
function plusMinus(arr) {
  var freq = {
    posetive: 0,
    negative: 0,
    zero: 0
  };
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if( arr[i] < 0) {
      freq.negative++;
    } else if(arr[i] > 0) {
      freq.posetive++;
    } else {
      freq.zero++;
    }
  } 
  for(var key in freq){
    console.log((freq[key]/arr.length).toFixed(6));
  }
}
plusMinus([1,1,0,-1,-1]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could take an object with predifined properties, this prevents each loop for checking the existence and take an array of keys for getting the result in a wanted order.

```js
function plusMinus(arr) {
    var freq = { 1: 0, '-1': 0, 0: 0 },
        i, key;

    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        freq[arr[i]]++;
    }

    for (key of [1, -1, 0]) {
        console.log((freq[key] / arr.length).toFixed(6));
    }
}

plusMinus([1, 1, 0, -1, -1]);
```

Comment: The number can be any integer according the question. You might have to do: `freq[Math.sign(arr[i])]++`

Comment: @adiga, right, for any integer, the sign sould be sufficient.

Comment: @NinaScholz the order is right now but still deletes duplicates, the output should be 0.4,0.4,0.2   but its giving 0.4,0.2 , why is that?

Comment: i don't understand the last output. what do you get?

Answer (score 0):

You can use reduce.

Here idea is

- First loop through original array and check for the value.
- If value is zero we increment count of `zero` key.
- If value is `positive` we increment count of `pos` key.
- If value is `negative` we increment count of `neg` key.
- Finally we divide each count by length of array.

```js
let arr = [1,1,0,-1,-1]

let op = arr.reduce((op,inp)=>{
  if(inp === 0){
    op.zero.count++
  } else if (inp > 0){
    op.pos.count++;
  } else {
    op.neg.count++;
  }
  return op
},{zero:{count:0},pos:{count:0},neg:{count:0}})


let final = Object.entries(op).map(([key,value])=>({
  [key] : value.count / arr.length
}))

console.log(final)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `Array.reduce` and the resulting array will have the fraction of positive number at the '0'th index, negative at '1'st and zero at the '2'nd index.

Now if you want to control the count of the number of elements after decimal point, use `Array.map` at the end to transform it.

```js
const array = [1,1,0,-1,-1];
function plusMinus(arr){
  const output = arr.reduce((acc, ele) => {
  if(ele > 0){
    acc[0] = ((acc[0] || 0 ) + 1 / arr.length);
  }
  if(ele < 0){
    acc[1] = ((acc[1] || 0 ) + 1 / arr.length);
  }
  if(ele === 0) {
    acc[2] = ((acc[2] || 0 ) + 1 / arr.length);
  }
  return acc;
  }, []).map(ele => ele.toFixed(6));
 console.log(...output);
}
plusMinus(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `reduce`, `map` and `filter`:

```js
const arr = [1, 1, 0, -1, -1];

const counts = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if (!curr) acc[0]++;
  else if (curr > 0) acc[1]++;
  else acc[2]++;
  return acc
}, [0, 0, 0]);

const result = counts.map(e => e / arr.length).filter((e, i, a) => a.indexOf(e) == i);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Math.sign is your friend here.
[Math.sign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sign)

Also lodash would really help this snippet to be cleaner, I highly recommend _.countBy. [Lodash .countBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#countBy)

Here's the code.

```js
const plusMinus = (numbers) => {
  // Count by Sign (-1, 0 1)
  const countSign = _.countBy(numbers, Math.sign);
  // _.countBy return object, of counted { '1': 2, '0': 1, '-1': 2 } 
  
  // Print them in orders
  const printOrder = [1, -1, 0];
  printOrder.forEach(sign => {
    console.log((countSign[sign] / numbers.length).toFixed(6));
  });
}

const testArr = [1,1,0,-1,-1];
plusMinus(testArr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another one-line solution using `Array.reduce()` and `Array.forEach()` functions:

```js
const plusMinus = arr => arr
  .reduce((res, curr) => ++res[!curr ? 2 : curr < 0 ? 1 : 0] && res, [0, 0, 0])
  .forEach(i => console.log((i / arr.length).toFixed(6)));

plusMinus([1, 1, 0, -1, -1]);
```